# Accessing the elements of a list in a list - python

Tags: python

I need to access the elements of a list in a list.

I have tried the following code:

```
connections ={}
for i in connections_with_names:
    connections['dog']=[dict1[i] for i in dict2[i] if i not in connections_with_names[0]['dog']]
```

But I am getting back:

```
KeyError: 0
```

In addition, `connections_with_names['dog']` looks like this:

```
[['furry',
  'loud',
  'shed']]
```

I need the `for i in dict2[i] if i not in connections_with_names[0]['dog']]` to be able to access the 3 elements (furry, loud, shed) and exclude those elements. I think the issue has to do with the `connections_with_names[0]` part but unsure.

Comment: Do you mean `connections_with_names['dog'][0]` rather than `connections_with_names[0]['dog']`?

Comment: Thanks @JosephSible, I tried that as well. I did not get any errors but It did not exclude any of the elements of ```connections_with_names['dog']```

Comment: `connections_with_names` is a list contains another list you can't treat it like a list containing a dictionary like in your code `connections_with_names[0]['dog']`,  also what is the contents of `dict1` and `dict2`